# Watermark featured image as soon as it is set on post edit page

Tags: post-thumbnails

I want to watermark featured image of specific category when featured image is set on post edit page. I made a small script which watermarks but how can I know that featured image has been set so that script function runs automatically before publishing the post?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Thumbnails" or "Featured" images are attachments with an entry in the `$wpdb->postmeta` table under the key `_thumbnail_id`. [A couple of different action hooks run when entries are added to postmeta](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.7.1/src/wp-includes/meta.php#L149).  I think that probably the one you want is `updated_{$meta_type}_meta`. In your case, `updated_post_meta`. Something like this:

```
add_action(
  'updated_post_meta',
  function ($meta_id, $object_id, $meta_key, $_meta_value ) {
    if ('_thumbnail_id' == $meta_key) {
      // take a good look around
      // var_dump($meta_id, $object_id, $meta_key, $_meta_value );
      // die;
    }
  },
  1,4
);
```

Your script would run where that commented section is. I have no idea how that script works, but there are the WordPress components.

In your pastebin code, which I trust you will be editing into the question as you should, you are using this code:

```
$old_featured_image = wp_get_attachment_url( get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->ID ) );
```

`$post` is not set in your function. That line will fail. But you are going a long way around anyway. `wp_get_attachment_url` requires a thumbnail ID. That ID is passed into the filter as `$_meta_value`. That line only needs to be:

```
$old_featured_image = wp_get_attachment_url( $_meta_value );
```

I can't swear the rest of the function will work after that change but I am always concerned when I see `exec`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried it with my watermarking function and couldn't get it to work. Here is the link you might like to see: http://pastebin.com/bJLxD522

Comment: Exactly what doesn't work? Also, site policy is that all relevant code be included in either the question or the answer, whichever is appropriate.

Comment: got it, working. Problem was within my code.