# water mark on featured post image in wordpress

Tags: post-thumbnails

As i read in this thread [Watermark featured image as soon as it is set on post edit page](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/124965/watermark-featured-image-as-soon-as-it-is-set-on-post-edit-page/280415?noredirect=1#comment415392_280415) seems to be possible reach what i need: i mean, add to every thumbnail of a featured post image a watermark... just on a featured image..not on all the site images...

Comment: so what is the actual question? what code have you tried yourself?

Comment: Welcome to WordPress Stack Exchange! Please [take the tour](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/tour) and visit our [help center](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help) to learn how this website works. We're here to help people but we're not here to do free work. You will need to edit your question using the `edit` link above and add in what you've tried and what specifically you need help with.